# Html.ActionLink with ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag, html.actionlink

I currently have a ActionLink in Razor that looks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to News", "Index")
```

However, I wish to add a ViewBag to it

```
@ViewBag.groupid
```

Thus the rendering of the ActionLink to know to instead of being simply:

```
<a href="/">Back to News</a>
```

To instead have changed the URL to be Index/@ViewBag.groupid    ( Index/5 )

so that URL is then

```
/Index/5   ( where 5 is the ViewBag.groupid)
```

Comment: There's an overload (a few actually) that take `routeValues`.  Set `routeValues` to a new anonymous object with an `id` property set to `ViewBag.groupid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an overload (a few actually) that take routeValues. Set routeValues to a new anonymous object with an id property set to ViewBag.groupid.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to News", "Index", "controller name", 
                 new {id = ViewBag.groupid}, null)
```

Comment: That works,  just didn't need ending semicolon  ;    thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use this format :

```C#
@Html.ActionLink("title", actionMethodName","ControllerName", new { id = value }, null);
```

for your example it would be :

```C#
@Html.ActionLink("back to news", "Index", "your controller name", new { id = @ViewBag.groupid }, null);
```

Comment: close, no @ in front of ViewBag , and no ending ;   thx though

Comment: I was writing the response while was disconnecting , and for that reason my answer is repeated. sorry for that

Comment: You are correct the @ in front of ViewBag still allows it to work.  However it doesn't highlight in yellow because it is not needed,  I'm surprised it still works both with and without.